# Is it possible to use only the name of the files instead of writing out the entire path?

Tags: python, path

Is it possible to use only the name of the files instead of writing out the entire path in line 4 and 5?

```
 [1] from win32com import client
 [2] excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
 [3] word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
 [4] doc = word.Documents.Open(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\Table1.docx")
 [5] book=excel.Workbooks.Open(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\Table1.xlsx")
    sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
    sheet.Range("A1:D5").Copy()    
    wdRange = doc.Content
    wdRange.Collapse(0)
    wdRange.PasteExcelTable(False, True, False) 
    
    import os
    os.remove('Table2.xlsx')
    
    book.SaveAs('Table2.xlsx')
    book.Close()
    excel.Quit()
    doc.SaveAs('TableOne.docx')
    doc.Close()
    word.Quit()
```

I've tried doing this, but it gives me an error:

```
doc = word.Documents.Open('Table1.docx')
book = excel.Workbooks.Open('Table1.xlsx')
```

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Sorry, we couldn't find Table1.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Updated Code:

```
from win32com import client
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template")

excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open('Table1.docx')
book = excel.Workbooks.Open('Table1.xlsx')
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1:D5").Copy()    
wdRange = doc.Content
wdRange.Collapse(0)
wdRange.PasteExcelTable(False, True, False) 

os.remove('Table2.xlsx')

book.SaveAs('Table2.xlsx')
book.Close()
excel.Quit()
doc.SaveAs('TableOne.docx')
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

Comment: os.chdir() changes the current directory of the Python process. It does not change the current directory of either Word or Excel. Therefore you will have to pass the full path to Word or Excel or be happy to read/write from their current directories. excel.Path or word.Path will give you the current path of each process, but it is a read only property, so you cannot change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Simply move your `import os` line to the top of the file (before or after the `win32com` import, it doesn't matter), then on the next line put

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template")
```

You can now omit the full paths you send to `word.Documents.open()` and `excel.Workbooks.open()`, like you show in the lower part of your question.

Comment: I did what you mentioned and I'm getting the same error. @MattDMo

Comment: I added my new code at the bottom of the question

Comment: this is the error: com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Sorry, we couldn't find Table1.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: The problem with `os.chdir()` is that it is changing the directory of the Python process. However, Word is in a different process. Within Word VBA, there is a way to change the process current directory, but I know of no way to do it from the Word automation model. (Might be a way, but I don't know it.) So for now, you'll have to pass the full path to the functions. Substitute "Excel" for "Word" when applicable.